# "Resource file has already set" warning in Azure Devops, and variables unavailable

Tags: azure-devops

Today, the Deployment jobs in our Azure Devops pipelines are all showing the warning:

`##[warning]Resource file has already set to: D:\a\_tasks\AzureKeyVault_1e244d.........\1.212.0\node_modules\azure-pipelines-tasks-azure-arm-rest-v2\module.json`

<strike>Additionally, variables passed into the jobs are being passed as empty strings, resulting in failures.</strike> - This seems to be resolved as of 3rd November.

Needless to say, we have re-run our pipelines multiple times to no avail, and have reviewed the Azure Devops status page - which shows no issues.

The pipelines were all working normally yesterday (1st November).

The warnings seem to appear for any deployment job referencing a variable group linked to a key vault, e.g.

```yaml
  - deployment: MyDeployment
    pool:
      vmImage: ubuntu-20.04
    variables:
    - group: MyKeyVaultLinkedVariableGroup
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi have you tried to use `- task: AzureKeyVault@2` or latest Key Vautl task with version to retrieve the secret instead of setting with variable groups?

And if you are using local self hosted agent, you could refer to local agent folder and delete the key vault tool files and run the key vault task to download the key vault tool again.

=============================================================

**Updated 11/14**

Please check the Github ticket for [Warnings about resource file already set](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/17127) for the latest release version of ***KeyVault*** for the fix that will be rolled out.

================================================================

**Update 12/2**

[quick update](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/17127#:%7E:text=Hi%20all%2C%20Quick%20update%3A)

> Azure KV version 213 (both task and variable group) which fixes the
> warning issue, has been rolled out to south Brazil and EUS2 region for
> now. There is a slight delay, but version 213 will be rolled out to
> all regions and users by end of December 1st week.

Comment: Hi @CeenoQi-MSFT.  We're using Microsoft hosted agents.

I could experiment with the `AzureKeyVault@2` task, although to be honest this is lower priority for us now the pipelines are running and the only issue is the warnings.

Comment: @Mike ,hi mike, you could check the latest update for Azure KV version 213 for test. If the issue persists, don't forget to share with us.

Comment: Hi @Ceeno Qi-MSFT.  Thanks for checking in.  It looks like the change has rolled out to our region.  We're no longer seeing any warnings :)

Answer (score 1):

At least what i can tell now is that some versions of the Agent (2.206.1 - 2.213.2) is still downloading the AzureKeyVault Task with Version 1.212.0 which is causing these Warnings to appear. Therefore thats an issue of the AzureKeyVault Task and AzureAgents in common.

related to the Github entry ([here](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/17127)) this is already solved, but it might take a while to get rolled out to the agents out there. Also you can force an Update of Agents in the

**Project Settings -> Agent Pools -> Select the Pool -> Agents Tab**

either by clicking "Update All Agents" or by clicking the three dot menu on an agent and update this agent itself.
This might lead that self hosted agents are not correctly restarted and need to get started manually, how to do that:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-linux?view=azure-devops#how-do-i-restart-the-agent

with version 2.213 this issue should be fixed, according to the github entry but this sometimes is not the case.

Updates will follow if there are any changes on the github entry later on

Update 2022.11.25:
In Most regions the Azure Agents are already rolled out but the AzureKeyVault Task is still on 1.212, according to the github issue the rollouts of this task to other regions will happen until the 1st week of December.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an Azure Key Vault issue.

[https://portal.azure.com/?quickstart=true#view/Microsoft_Azure_Health/AzureHealthBrowseBlade/~/serviceIssues](https://portal.azure.com/?quickstart=true#view/Microsoft_Azure_Health/AzureHealthBrowseBlade/%7E/serviceIssues)

[image: Screenshot from Azure Portal]

Comment: Actually, I think it quite unlikely that this is the source of the problem.   I am also seeing these warnings, and it started for me yesterday.  My builds actually succeed, but I get a ton of these warnings.

Comment: Some additional internet searching led me to this: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/14284 which is not the exact same situation but seems likely to have the same underlying cause.  See this comment from the discussion on that issue:

> This is happening probably because KubernetesV1 is dependent on azure-pipelines-tasks-azure-arm-rest-v2 which has the an older version of azure-pipelines-task-lib, while we have specified the latest version in it's package.json. This should not have any effect on the pipeline run.

Comment: hi mike, is this issue still observed? And could you share your steps to reproduce this issue?

Comment: @CeenoQi-MSFT We are also getting the warning in a bunch of my pipelines as of yesterday. It seems to be any that are using a **Variable Group** that reads from a Key Vault; I am not using `AzureKeyVault` task in any of them, but the ones with the stream of warnings all have the linked variable groups in common

Comment: @CeenoQi-MSFT, as of yesterday, like pinkfloydx33 we are still seeing the warnings, but our pipelines are now succeeding.  So the issue regarding variables being passed as emtpty strings looks to be resolved.  I've updated my question to clarify the steps for reporduction.

Comment: Same for me, we get a bunch of these warnings but the pipeline works as expected.

Comment: @Mike, hi mike, in your warning message, i found that your task is referencing the  keyvault task version of 1.212.0 `D:\a\_tasks\AzureKeyVault_1e244d.........\1.212.0`.

We suppose that you could follow this ticket [AzureKeyVault v1.212.0 #17127](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/17127) for more latest updates.

Comment: @CeenoQi-MSFT can you please ping me (alexbat) internally?

Answer (score 0):

I tried navigating to ***project settings*** --> ***Service connection***

[image]

[image]

and deleted the service connection and the issue got resolved